# Moving Clocks Time Problem

Tags: special-relativity

http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/Special_relativity_rel_sim/index.html

Talking about the situation of clocks shown on this page. Clocks A&B. Now suppose clock B is moving towards A with constant velocity. A sees B coming towards it, and figures out that the clock B is running slow, and by symmetry B says the same. Now, B & A meet at a space-time and actually compare readings. Now they will know one of the clocks ran slower. How is this possible

Comment: The resolution is the same as that of the famous Twin Paradox. Searching this term will probably get you want you want.

Comment: @BMS No one changed frames here.

Comment: Where did you get "Now they will know one of the clocks ran slower"?

Comment: @WillO When they meet they can compare their clocks.

Comment: L-L:  And how will that tell them which clock ran slower?

Comment: @WillO You write your reading on a piece of paper and send it to the other person, no matter when he receives, because of the orderness of the real number system, one of the clocks will have a lesser reading and thus will be running slow.

Comment: L-L:  Where did you get "and thus will be running slow"?